# item is undefined in ng-repeat - angular-datatable

Tags: angularjs

I'm using this for displaying table and pagination: https://github.com/samu/angular-table

I have a table that's filled using `ng-repeat` and the above module. I am not able to access each item in the `ng-repeat(ae in getInvoices)` `ae` is undefined.

I also have a button inside a `td` inside the `ng-repeat`(EdButton). On click of the button, I pass the current item details to a function. But the current item(`ae`) is undefined.

So I tried sending it like this to the function:

```
`getInvoiceExpenseItems(getInvoices[$index].exp_invoice_id)`
```

But when I add pagination, I get the first value of the array when I click the button(EdButton) on the second page of the pagination since the `$index` is 0 in the second page.

The table is displayed correctly with all the values

How do I get each item or send the correct index value?

```
 <tr ng-repeat="ae in getInvoices">
   <td  at-attribute="entry_date">{{getInvoices[$index].entry_date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
   <td  at-implicit at-attribute="exp_invoice_no"></td>
   <td  at-implicit at-attribute="vendor_name"></td>
   <td  at-implicit at-attribute="exp_ref_no"></td>
   <td  at-implicit at-attribute="payable"></td>
   <td>
      <button type="button"
          ng-click="getInvoiceExpenseItems(getInvoices[$index].exp_invoice_id, ae); meminfomodel();   expn = null; ">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      </button>
      <button type="button"
         ng-click="deletecustdetailsmodel(getInvoices[$index].exp_invoice_id,getInvoices[$index].customer_id,getInvoices[$index].association_id)">
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o red"></i>
      </button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

This is the array of objects:
`$scope.getInvoices = response.data.body.Data;`

```
:[  
     {  
        "exp_invoice_id":"1",
        "exp_invoice_no":"874589589865652",
        "exp_invoice_date":"21-7-2018",
        "payable":"15",
        "vendor_id":"4",
        "vendor_name":"brigadeVendorA",
        "customer_id":"5",
        "association_id":"10",
        "exp_ref_no":"exp\/bri\/1",
        "entry_date":"2018-07-07",
        "remarks":"ad"
     },
     {  
        "exp_invoice_id":"2",
        "exp_invoice_no":"874589589865111",
        "exp_invoice_date":"21-7-2018",
        "payable":"9",
        "vendor_id":"4",
        "vendor_name":"brigadeVendorA",
        "customer_id":"5",
        "association_id":"10",
        "exp_ref_no":"exp\/bri\/2",
        "entry_date":"2018-07-28",
        "remarks":"rem"
     }
```

]

Comment: did you check your getInvoices array has values?

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul yes, even the table is displayed with all the values

Comment: If ae is undefined, it means that you stored undefined inside your getInvoices array. So, post the relevant code: how do you initialize and populate getInvoices.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm using this https://github.com/samu/angular-table . The array does not have undefined in it. The table works and displays all the values. Angular table is an external module and it uses `at-attribute` to get keys of object in array and displays the values. It's just that `ae` is undefined.

Comment: ae is the current element of the array. That's what ng-repeat does. So **if** it's undefined, it means the array contains undefined elements. ng-repeat works fine. The problem is in your code. How do you know ae is undefined in the first place? And why don't you post the relevant code?

Comment: @JBNizet i've posted the array of objects. that's all I think is the relevant code.

Comment: That is not valid JS code. Valid JS code would be `$scope.getInvoices = [ ... ];`. It seems you deliberately refuse to post what you're being asked to post. Why? Don't you want our help? Post the code initializing the array. Post the code allowing you to determine that ae is undefined.

Comment: @JBNizet I know it's undefined because I checked in the console in debug mode. I passed `ae` on click of the button. I've changed the html too so that you can see the ng-click. In the html I've posted, I've passed `getInvoiceExpenseItems(getInvoices[$index].exp_invoice_id)` since `ae` is undefined

Comment: @JBNizet I've posted the array from the console. It's all there is to post. please tell me what you want me to post. I get the array from a web service. `$scope.getInvoices = response.data.body.Data;`

Comment: honestly your code looks fine, I dont understand why you are using this    at-implicit at-attribute    instead of simply    ae.exp_invoice_no    to render values

Comment: So ae is not undefined. ae is a variable that only exists in the scope of the ng-repeat directive. It's not a global variable. So you can't evaluate it in the console. Add {{ ae | json }} inside your first td, for example, and you'll see if it's undefined or not.

Comment: @JB Nizet I've left work now. But I did something like {{ae || 'randomstring' }} and I get the 'randomstring'. I guess it could be null or something else too. II'll have to try the | json on Monday

Comment: @boo did you actually try passing the ae to the getInvoiceExpenseItems() function and checking in the debugger if the ae is undefined or there is some other reason why you think ae is undefined?

Comment: @boo that it means it's indeed undefined, or null, or 0, or false, or the empty string. So check what your backend returns. That's where the problem is.

Comment: @Fakhar Ahmad Radio I did pass and check in the debugger. It is undefined. I'm using the at-implicit because the angular-datatable module requires it

Comment: @JB Nizet. I've posted what the backend sends.. there's no undefined or  null values in it.

Comment: Well, one of the two contradictory things you posted is wrong. You need to find which one.

Comment: @boo well considering everything, I think the issue is with the datatable module you are using, I suggest you to use this https://datatables.net/ instead, I have been using this datatable with angularjs for a while now without any issues and its fairly simple to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go through documentation of this [angular-table](https://github.com/samu/angular-table). You need not use `ng-repeat` after using this library directive for implementing the table. Just by declaring `at-table at-list="getInvoices"` on table element, it will by default consider `getInvoices` as array of objects & will iterate over its properties.

So, inside `tr` you've to define different `td` with properties you wanna display. You should make use of `at-title` attribute (from this plugin lib) to define column titles. Then, if you want to use filters on any property, you can right away use (along with binding) or you can create method for that & send the property value as a parameter and then filter it in controller using `$filter`. Here by default `item` is an object which is repeating (part of internal ng-repeat code of library), so, `item.propertyName` would get your required property. Similarly when you use buttons inside any `td` & use ng-click directive on it & want to pass object then, just pass `item` to any function & it'll send that particular row whole object.

Your updated view code can be :

```
<table at-table at-list="getInvoices" class="table table-striped">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td at-title="Entry Date">{{item.entry_date | date:"dd-MM-yyyy"}}</td>
      <td at-implicit at-attribute="exp_invoice_no"></td>
      <td at-implicit at-attribute="vendor_name"></td>
      <td at-implicit at-attribute="exp_ref_no"></td>
      <td at-implicit at-attribute="payable"></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" ng-click="getInvoiceExpenseItems($event, item)">
          <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="deletecustdetailsmodel($event, item)">
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o red"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Where those methods in controller can be:

```
 $scope.getInvoiceExpenseItems = function(event, item) {
    //Write logic of getting invoice of item 
    console.log(item);
  }

  $scope.deletecustdetailsmodel = function(event, item) {
    // Write logic of deleting particular item
    console.log(item);
  }
  // Below method used in case you want to filter something inside controller
  $scope.getFormatedDate = function(dateStr) {
    var date = new Date(dateStr);
    var formatted = $filter('date')(date, "dd-MM-yyyy");
    return formatted;
  }
```

Check the console after clicking respective buttons, you'll get complete object of that particular row (from array).

[**Demo Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/qSbVgblJbCB95hJJVvDm?p=preview)

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'll try it once I get to work. But what is `item`? I mean I haven't done anything like `item in ...` so how does it know what item is?

Comment: @boo It's part of library. So whatever array you pass to at-list, it'll internally work as: item in ... Check plunker example I've added.